# Rails minitest spec fails while it shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I'm currently trying to test a model in Rails project.

Spec shouldn't fail, but it does. Is there any way I can debug or log the process to understand which exactly part goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

First of all you must install ruby-debug.

```
sudo gem install ruby-debug
```

then you write

> debugger

immediately before the line you wish to start debugging.

Debugging your tests is not very different from debugging your code.

Rails already comes with byebug gem (uncomment it, if necessary):

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end
```

http://nanorails.com/articles/2006/07/14/a-better-rails-debugger-ruby-debug/

also Logging helps a lot to investigate and fix issues. Not only in test but also when you deploy it on production. You can log state of your models and other useful info. Also standard rails logging logs SQL that is send to the database so you can easily see what's going on there. SQL logging is on by default in dev and test and looks similar to this: